# Random color in listview data keeps changing while searching?

Tags: flutter, dart

**I have unknown list data fetch from API.
Here is my code where I declared random color for the list view.**

```
Widget employeeListBuilder() {
    return Scrollbar(
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      thickness: 6,
      radius: const Radius.circular(10),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: employee.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return ListViewWidget(
            name: employee[i].name.toString(),
            department: employee[i].department.toString(),
            color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)] ,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: because you're using the random method to get a color and when you search and text changes, data is processed again and thus random is getting called again resulting in random color

Comment: Can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code hope its help to you. Refer **[Primaries-Constant](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors/primaries-constant.html)**

```
color: Colors.primaries[i % Colors.primaries.length],
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways are there to get a random color. Some approaches listed below

- `Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0)`
- maintain a list with colors you want and get random color from them like below

```
  List colors = [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.yellow];
  Random random = new Random();

  final Color newColor = random.nextInt(3);
```

- `Random().nextInt(0xffffffff)`